# How to unblock other events during scrolling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've noticed that in mobile version of https://mail.google.com/ even during scrolling up and down the list of yr emails you can tap on any mail and it opens. I want to have same effect in my app on react, but I don't understand how to achive it. Every time during scrolling the screen tap-events are blocked and only after scrolling has stoped you can do something you want.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have events fired during scrolling events, you must handle the scrolling state of your screen through `useRef`. If your last screen position is different from the current position, you could then fire something during scrolling.

use this hook on your dependencies:

```
import { useRef, useLayoutEffect } from "react";

const isBrowser = typeof window !== `undefined`;

const getScrolledPosition = ({ element, useWindow }) => {
  if (!isBrowser) return { x: 0, y: 0 };

  const target = element ? element.current : document.body;
  const position = target.getBoundingClientRect();
  return useWindow
    ? { x: window.scrollX, y: window.scrollY }
    : {
        x: position.left,
        y: position.top,
        height: position.height,
        bottom: position.bottom,
      };
};

export const useScrollPosition = (effect, deps, element, useWindow, wait) => {
  const position = useRef(getScrolledPosition({ useWindow }));
  let throttleTimeout = null;
  const callBack = () => {
    const currPos = getScrolledPosition({ element, useWindow });
    effect({ prevPos: position.current, currPos });
    position.current = currPos;
    throttleTimeout = null;
  };
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (wait) {
        if (throttleTimeout === null) {
          throttleTimeout = setTimeout(callBack, wait);
        }
      } else {
        callBack();
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, deps);
};
```

below is an example of how you could call this hook and do fire events during scrolling

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);
  const [paintToolbar, setPaintToolbar] = useState(false);

  useScrollPosition(
    ({ prevPos, currPos }) => {
      const isShow = currPos.y > prevPos.y;
      if (isShow !== visible) setVisible(isShow);
      const below100vH = currPos.bottom <= 0;
      !below100vH ? setPaintToolbar(false) : setPaintToolbar(true);
    },
    [paintToolbar, visible],
    false,
    false,
    150
  );
```

Please let me know if you have any doubts

=D